# GIS-based data visualization and maintenance tool

Tags: web-development, database, maintenance, map, crud

### Background

Looking to leverage an existing GIS system for exploring organizational data.

### Architecture

The following figure represents a high-level overview of the system's desired features:

[image]

The most basic usage would be as follows:

1. The user visits a web site.
2. The system presents a map (having regions, cities, and buildings).
3. The user drills-down on the map to a particular building.
4. The system provides a basic CRUD interface.
5. The user can view and modify information about personnel (e.g., their assigned teams), equipment (e.g., network appliances), applications, and the building itself (e.g., contact and phone numbers).

Ideally, all the components should be open-source (or otherwise free).

### Problem

This must be a small project that needs a quick (but functional) prototype, mostly to confirm whether or not such a system would be useful in the long term.

### Questions

- What software components would you use to quickly develop a working prototype?
- What open-source solutions already exist, if any?

### Ideas

Here is what I am thinking:

- [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.org/) - Define the regions, cities, and sites
- [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/) - Display an interactive, clickable map
- [geoJSON](https://github.com/JasonSanford/GeoJSON-to-Google-Maps) - Protocol between PostGIS and Google Maps
- [Seam](http://seamframework.org/Home/WhySeam) - CRUD interface

### Custom Development

For example, this would entail:

1. Installation and configuration

   1. Configure SSH for remote logins
   2. Subversion (or git)
   3. PostgreSQL
   4. PostGIS
   5. Java
   6. Tomcat
   7. Seam
   8. JasperReports
2. Enter GIS information into PostGIS
3. Aggregate data sources into PostgreSQL database
4. Develop starting page for map interface
5. Develop clickable Google Maps interface
6. Develop summary reports
7. Develop CRUD interface using Seam for data maintenance

Surely something like this already exists?

Thank you!

Comment: did you check http://gis.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: No; SO people suggested PSE; GSE is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We went with the following:

1. [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) + [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/)
2. [Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) + [Embedded Jetty](https://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty) + [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
3. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) + [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) + [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)
4. [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) + [Mod Tile](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_tile)

We removed the reporting and data maintenance requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, Im developing a similar system for oil & gas, with Google Maps API v3. We chose to use CouchDB for the part of your diagram that includes GIS data, central repository, and other data sources. The idea behind this is one container to hold disparate sources of data with different types of structure, and also actual data files that represent GIS layers, logs, tickets, etc.

Also the capability of being able to host actual applications directly from the DB server is helpful for processing/uploading data.

Ultimately for our system which was faced with the prospect of bringing together old + messy + unorganized data, This NoSQL + Schema-less setup has made working with different types of data a pleasure.